# How to reallocate memory for a 2D float array?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I tried the following to reallocate a 2D `float` array whose size chages from 2X2 to 3X3. The code throws a `segfault` while trying to `realloc` memory for `weights[2]`.

```
num_vertices = 2;
float **weights = malloc(num_vertices*sizeof(float *));      // weight array matrix
for(i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++){
    weights[i] = malloc(num_vertices*sizeof(float));
}

num_vertices = 3;
weights = realloc(weights, num_vertices*sizeof(float *));      // weight array matrix
for(i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++){       
    weights[i] = realloc(weights[i], num_vertices*sizeof(float));
}
```

Of course, I can `free` the 2D array and `malloc` again, but I was looking for a more elegant solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `weights[2]` contains garbage after you realloc `weights`.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
new_vertices = 3;
weights = realloc(weights, new_vertices*sizeof(float *));
for(i = 0; i < new_vertices; i++)
{
    if (i >= num_vertices)
        weights[i] = NULL;
    weights[i] = realloc(weights[i], new_vertices*sizeof(float));
}
num_vertices = new_vertices;
```

Note that you have a potential memory leak if realloc ever fails. Since you have no error checking yet though this probably doesn't matter for now.

Answer (score 3):

The realloc of `weights[2]` is trying to realloc unallocated memory, since `weights[2]` was never assigned any pointer.

Usually, if you want a 2D array, just use `wegihts[width*y + x]` to index into the array, instead of making an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't loop to the *new* vertice count, as that part of the outer array is not allocated yet and contain uninitialized data. Instead loop to the new `num_vertices - 1` and reallocate, then create a brand new `weights[num_verticees - 1]`.